# Restrict certain user roles to access a view page programatically drupal8

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have a view for documents list. I want to restrict certain user roles per department to access this view page.  How to solve this? Any hook function  available?

Comment: will the built in access configuration of view not help ? does it need to be done programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the built in access control of views

[image]

[image]